# In React, speed up large initial fetch of data when web app loads

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, local-storage

Similar to the project I am working on, [this website](https://www.baseball-reference.com/) has a search bar at the top of its home page:

[image]

On the linked website, the search bar works seemingly immediately when visiting the website. According to [their own website](https://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/index.shtml), there have been roughly ~20K MLB players in MLB history, and this is a good estimate for the number of dropdown items in this select widget.

On my project, it currently takes 10-15 seconds to make this fetch (from MongoDB, using Node + Express) for a table with ~15mb of data that contains the data for the select's dropdown items. This 15mb of data is as small as I could make this table, as it includes only two keys (1 for the `id`, and 1 for the `name` for each dropdown). This table is large because there are more than 150K options to choose from in my project's select widget. I currently have to disable the widget for the first 15 seconds while the data loads, which results in a bad user experience.

Is there any way to make the data required for the select widget immediately available to the select when users visit, that way the widget does not have to be disabled? In particular:

- Can I use localstorage to store this table in the users browser? is 15MB too big for localstorage? This table changes / increases in size daily (not too persistent), and a table in localstorage would then be outdated the next day, no?
- Can I avoid all-together having to do this fetch? Potentially there is a way to load the correct data into react only when a user searches for that user?
- Some other approach?

Saving / fetching quicker for 15mb of data for this select will improve our react app's user experience by quite a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data on the site you link to is basically 20k in size. It does not contain all the players but fetches the data as needed when you click on a link in the drop-down. So if you have 20Mb of searchable data, then you need to find a way to only load it as required. How to do that sensibly depends on the nature of the data. Many search bars with large result sets behind them will use a typeahead search where the user's input is posted back as they type (with a decent debounce interval) and the search results matching the user's input sent back in real time (usually with a limit of, say, the first 20 or 50 results).

So basically the answer is to find a way to only serve up the data that the user needs rather than basically downloading the entire database to the browser (option 2 of your list). You must obviously provide a search API to allow that to happen.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this. Are you familiar with any libraries / approaches to do this in React?

Comment: It's really as simple as a parameterised GET request via axios or similar (axios seems to the default library). The challenge is building the API endpoint. Here's a tutorial for something similar: https://codeytek.com/live-search-search-react-live-search-in-react-axios-autocomplete-pagination/

Comment: Awesome thanks, I will read this. I'm surprised that this approach works at all to be honest. I would have thought that any approach that fetches data after **each** letter typed in the search by a user would be laggy / buggy as there is still some non-zero time needed for each fetch.

Comment: how can you tell that the data linked on the site is basically 20kb in size? I inspected the widget but didn't see the options

Comment: That is why you add a debounce delay - you wait a short time in order not to spam the server with requests. Note that you can also of course wait for the user to click search if it's a more complex search.

Comment: network tab - first item is called 'players'. If you look at the response, it is the HTML content of that drop down. You see the size is 22.1kb.

Comment: Refetching on "clicking search" is not frequent enough. Okay thanks again!

Comment: To reassure you it works, I wrote a similar search for a hospital application where the backend could have many thousands of patients. We used elasticsearch on the server for speed, but mongo would be fine.